# Portable powershell, minimal bundle

Tags: powershell-core, powershell-7.0

Which files are necessary from the archive** for `pwsh.exe` to properly run?

So that the rest(things like modules for xml) could be included on demand. Especially considering that the archive includes Windows-specific modules.

---

** PowerShell-7.0.1-win-x86.zip from [releases](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases)

Answer (score 0):

its Self contained. you need all files and subfolders to run and make pwsh portable

Comment: any official sources to back that claim?